# How combine three inputs into one string value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I'm creating a client-comment section page which I'm tring to get the original word format being entered by the user and save it to the database using t-sql. So I'm saving the string comment to the database which will be displayed as comments in the comment page. These are what I'm tryng to combine in order for me to get the right output as shown below...

Codes to bypass single qoutes through sql to work:

```
string comment = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox2.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
```

Codes to carry on carriage return

```
string comment = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox2.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />"));
```

Codes to carry on spacing and indentions

```
string comment = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox2.Text.Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
```

So I tried something like this:

```
string comment = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox2.Text.Replace("'", "''")) +  Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox2.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />")) + Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox2.Text.Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
```

but the codes to bypass single qoutes through sql to work and the codes to carry on spacing and indentions are not working...How do I correct my codes? How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't `HtmlEncode` text that goes to the database: what if you later want to display it in a javascript popup? Store the unencoded text in the database and encode it (with the correct encoding) just before displaying to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the conversions to the result of the previous conversions.

For example:

```
string comment = TextBox2.Text.Replace("'", "''");
comment = comment.Replace("\r\n", "<br />");
comment = Server.HtmlEncode(comment.Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
```

I don't see a decent way to do that in one line.

Comment: @Paperjam: I was just copy / pasting from the original question.  You're right.  That's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
string comment = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox2.Text
                    .Replace("'", "''")
                    .Replace("\r\n", "<br />")
                    .Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
```